What is the fastest way to highlight vertices or edges when using raycast on a dense mesh?
How can I highlight edges/verts by hovering them on a dense mesh fast? How is the built in ruler in blender doing this so fast? when I do this in my addon on a dense mesh it updates the redraws highlight really slow.
Which ways is the best to raycast to find the vert and draw the highlight fast during mousemove on a dense mesh?

I don't entirely understand your problem and specifically how you raycast, but in general native compiled code will be faster than Python probably by at least 1 order of magnitude. For performance on a lot of geometry you might want to consider using geometry nodes to evaluate big chunks of data, as there a single node can iterate over all elements, and each node is implemented in C++, so you get close to perfect performance.
